# Accessing HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

```
Class DataAcess{
private Map<Integer, Person> persList;
  public DataAccess(Map persList){
     this.persList = persList; 
  } 
  public List<Person> getPersByDept(String dept){ 
   \\what is the efficient way to get data 
  }
}
Class Person { 
  Integer id;
  Dept dept; 
} 
Class Dept { 
  String id; 
}
```

What the most efficient way to access the hashmap in getPersByDept method to get list of person objects that have a particular dept id?

Comment: Your code is nowhere near compiling. Post **real** code as a [mcve]. And then questino would you would want to keep a map of `<Integer, Person>` when you need to retrieve by a `String`.

Comment: What are you storing in personlist hashmap integer key value ?

Comment: just updated, Person have Integer and Dept. consider that integer to the be the key as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want simply to search without any additional structures:

```
 public List<Person> getPersByDept(String dept) {
   return persList.values().stream()
             .filter(person-> Objects.nonNull(person.dept))
             .filter(person -> Objects.equals(person.dept.id, dept))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But if you want to be more efficient, then you need to prepare a map:

```
class DataAcess {
    private Map<Integer, Person> persList;
    private Map<String, List<Person>> personsByDebt;
    public DataAcess(Map persList) {
        this.persList = persList;
        this.personsByDebt=this.persList.values().stream()
                .filter(person-> Objects.nonNull(person.dept))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(person-> person.dept.id));
    }

    public List<Person> getPersByDept(String dept) {
        return personsByDebt.getOrDefault(dept, Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```